# Expired licenses - unused computers

Tags: licensing, expired

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We have around 20 licenses that have expired. The programs that came with the license is still installed on the computers but has since the license expired been unplugged and locked inside storage.

My question is:

Generally, when it comes to licenses, are you obligated to remove the programs even if the computers they're installed on are not used and can not be used(Most of the power supplies has been removed and are used elsewhere)? If, for example, BSA comes knocking, will there be trouble?

Comment: Which license for what ? Windows license ? TSE license ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there is no general answer for your question. It depends on what's written in the [software license agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license_agreement) (or EULA).

The best thing you can do here is to ask the vendor of the product.

Comment: The industry needs a standardized checkbox form that describes 99% of all license options. Even though there is user outcry for it, no one will do it as they reserve the right to "innovate" (i.e., be non-standard). Some even pretend the right to change license rights at any moment, as if there was even a legal precedent for this!

Answer (score 1):

Some EULAs do state explicitly that when you are no longer licensed you must destroy all copies of the software. While I personally agree that an inoperable machine with unllicensed software installed should be OK, if a license explicitly states removal of the software after license expiry, then that may be the best option in terms of liability.

That said, I a not a lawyer and as stated above the best solution would be to consult the EULA for the software and/or contact the vendor concerned

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the general purpose/intent behind software licenses revolves around actual usage, since these computers are shutdown and inoperable I would speculate that you are ok. Are you using this software on other computers with updated licenses? I would say that if you are done with the software then there is no wrong doing. Also, generally speaking, software with time limited licenses (such as virus protection et al.) usually limit their functionality when the license expires anyways implying that you are now operating in a license free mode.

I would say if you are really concerned about it try and find a copy of the license and see what it says.